# loop on tables in information schema to find their size and return a report

Tags: google-bigquery, execute, information-schema

I would like to find the number of records for a list of tables that start with a common prefix via a SQL query.

In BigQuery I am trying a combination of `CONCAT()` or `FORMAT()` along with `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` in `FOR` loops or `WHILE` loops that in my mind should eventually be executed with `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` but I am not able to setup the final query.

This is what I have:

```sql
DECLARE query_string STRING;

FOR record IN (
  select CONCAT(
    "SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt_rows,",
    "\"", table_name, "\"", " AS t_name ",
    "FROM ", CONCAT("`",table_schema,".",   table_name, "`" )
  ) AS MY_STMNT
FROM `<<my-project-id>>.<<my-dataset>>.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`
WHERE table_name LIKE "my-table-prefix__YYYY-MM-DDT%"
) DO
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
  -- 1st attempt:
  -- FORMAT( """
  --     %s
  --     """, record.MY_STMNT);

  -- 2nd attempt (this doesn't even execute because of "Syntax error: Unexpected keyword SET at xxx"):
  -- SET query_string = query_string || record.MY_STMNT || " UNION ALL ";
END FOR;
```

This fails because the results are separate as one for each table. I would Like all of them in one final output result where each row is:

1. table name as `t_name`
2. number of rows as `cnt_rows`

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use a string variable to accumulate SQL statements combined with `UNION ALL`.

The issue with my previous attempts was that I wanted to `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` at each iteration in the for loop, instead of doing it after the entire loop.

```sql
DECLARE query_string STRING;
SET query_string = "";

FOR record IN (
  -- dynamically build the SELECT query based on the data in INFORMATION_SCHEMA e.g.:
  -- - the table name
  -- - the number of rows in that table
  SELECT CONCAT(
    "SELECT ",
    "'", table_name, "'", " AS t_name, ",
    "COUNT(*) AS cnt_rows, ",
    "FROM ", CONCAT("`", table_schema, ".", table_name, "`")
  ) AS MY_STMNT
FROM `<<my-project-id>>.<<my-dataset>>.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`
WHERE table_name LIKE "my-table-prefix__YYYY-MM-DDT%"
) DO
  SET query_string = query_string || record.MY_STMNT || " UNION ALL ";
END FOR;

-- just add a dummy "last row" to make "UNION ALL" work
SET query_string = query_string || "SELECT 'x' AS t_name, 0 AS cnt_rows";
-- make sure we rank the output table by the number of records from biggest to smallest
SET query_string = query_string || " ORDER BY cnt_rows DESC";

-- to inspect the SQL query, just print it
SELECT query_string;

-- invoke the SQL query
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE query_string;
```

Be careful though: if you combine together with `UNION ALL` multiple complex SQL queries e.g. `SELECT`, then BigQuery may throw an error like this:

> Resources exceeded during query execution: Not enough resources for query planning - too many subqueries or query is too complex.. at [1:1]

This of course depends on the content of the SQL query you are building. The procedure above may apply to your case without throwing errors when invoked at scale.